# Memory exhaustion for single vector function R

Tags: r

I want to run a single function (i.e. [calculating the Gini coefficient](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/DescTools/versions/0.99.19/topics/Gini) using the `DescTools` library) on a vector of length 40k.

```
set.seed(42)
my_vec = sample(1:100000, 40000, replace = T)

#the function to get the Gini with confidence interval
DescTools::Gini(my_vec, conf.level = 0.99)
```

Calculating the confidence interval (calculating just the Gini coefficient without the confidence interval works perfectly in no time) results in some memory issues on my machine (64 bit R version, 8 GB RAM) and returns

`Error: vector memory exhausted (limit reached?)`

To solve this, I looked into these options:

- increase memory available to R but have not found an option for that on the Mac (`memory.limit()` seems to be only for Windows)
- Run the function in parallel using the `parallel` R library

I'm struggling with the latter because the function does not require any iteration over multiple columns. So I'd not expect a parallelization to work:

```
mclapply(my_vec, function(x) Gini(x, unbiased = T, conf.level = 0.99), mc.cores = 3) #does not work
```

Is there a way to avoid the memory issue, and if parallelization is a solution, how could I implement it for the one vector? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I imagine that the main memory usage comes from storing the bootstrapped samples for the confidence interval calculation. You could try to reduce the number of bootstrap samples by setting `R = 100` (default is `R = 1000`); whether this will be sufficient is a different question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an implementation of the [Lorenz curve and the Gini index in RevoScaleR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/machine-learning-server/r-reference/revoscaler/rxlorenz) that allows you to obtain calculations by chunks, regardless of the size of the vector.

```
set.seed(42)
my_vec = data.frame(V1 = sample(1:100000, 40000, replace = T))

# Compute Lorenz
lorenzOut <- rxLorenz(orderVarName = "V1", data = my_vec)

# Compute the Gini Coefficient
giniCoef <- rxGini(lorenzOut)
giniCoef
0.335597
```

**CI:**

```
boot <- replicate(1000, rxGini(rxLorenz(orderVarName = "V1", 
                                data = my_vec[sample.int(nrow(my_vec), nrow(my_vec), replace = TRUE), , drop = FALSE], reportProgress = 0)))

summary(boot)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
 0.3315  0.3347  0.3356  0.3356  0.3364  0.3396 

quantile(boot, probs = c(0.005, 0.995))
     0.5%     99.5% 
0.3324822 0.3389219
```

Comment: I'm curious: Can `rxGini` calculate bootstrap-based CIs as well?

Comment: Not directly, but it allows you to program it easily. The problem of `DescTools :: Gini` is that it returns NAs by overflow and even if you do the bootstrap by chunks you will not get the desired result with big data.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I wasn't aware of the RevoScaleR package. A simpler workaround is even your solution with the own bootstrapping via `replicate(...)`. Might not work with more enormous data sets though - I agree.